# Why is the subspace topology defined as it is?

Tags: general-topology

Given a topological space $(X, \tau)$, and $Y \subset X$, the subspace topology on $Y$ is defined to be
$$\tau_Y = \{Y \cap U : U \in \tau\}.$$
The definition itself is clear and self-explanatory, what I am wondering here is why is it defined this why? Is it so that the collection of open sets within $Y$ do indeed form a topology?

Comment: It should be the smallest (coarsest) topology so that the inclusion map is continuous.

Comment: @Michael I see, to be really pedantic, why do we require the exactly?

Comment: What else would you do?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan You mean making the inclusion maps continuous? I suppose it is the obvious thing to do, I was just wondering if there was something more to it.

Comment: making certain collections of maps continuous is exactly our main motivation for defining certain topologies. The inclusion map gives the subspace topology. Using the projection maps on a product space gives rise to the product topology. Using a bunch of semi-norms on a vector space gives rise to the definition for certain topological vector spaces etc.

Comment: There are different ways to look at topology. You can think about convergence.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can of course define many topologies $\tau_Y$ on the set $Y$, but a minimal requirement is certainly that the inclusion function $i : (Y,\tau_Y) \to (X,\tau_X)$ becomes continuous. Let us call such a topology *admissible* (this is just an ad hoc notation).

Obviously there exist a finest admissible topology $\tau_Y^f$ (the discrete topology) and a coarsest admissible topology $\tau_Y^c$ (take the intersection of all admissible topologies). Moreover, the set $\tau_Y^s = \{U \cap Y \mid U \in \tau_X\}$ occurring in your question is easily seen to be a topology on $Y$; it is admissible because $i^{-1}(U) = U \cap Y \in \tau_Y^s$ for all $U \in \tau_X$.

We have $\tau_Y^c = \tau_Y^s$. The inclusion $\tau_Y^c \subset \tau_Y^s$ holds by definition, and since $\tau_Y^c$ is admissible, we have $U \cap Y = i^{-1}(U) \in \tau_Y^c$ for all $U \in \tau_X$, thus $\tau_Y^s \subset \tau_Y^c$.

This explains the special role of $\tau_Y^s$ among admissible topologies: *It is the coarsest admissible topology on $Y$.*

Let us now change perspective. We call a topology $\tau_Y$ on $Y$ *subspace topology* if it has the following universal property:

> A function $f : (Z,\tau_Z) \to (Y,\tau_Y)$, where $(Z,\tau_Z)$ is any topological space, is continuous if and only $i \circ f : (Z,\tau_Z) \to (X,\tau_X)$
> is continuous.

That is, the continuity of functions into $(Y,\tau_Y)$ can be detected by regarding them as functions into the ambient $(X,\tau_X)$. This is a very reasonable approach to introduce a topology on $Y$.

1. Each subspace topology  $\tau_Y$ is admissible:
   The identity $id: (Y,\tau_Y) \to (Y,\tau_Y)$ is continuous, thus $i = i \circ id$ is continuous.
2. There exists at most one subspace topology on $Y$:
   If $\tau_Y, \tau'_Y$ are subspace topologies, then both $id : (Y,\tau_Y) \to (Y,\tau'_Y)$ and $id : (Y,\tau'_Y) \to (Y,\tau_Y)$ are continuous by 1. and the universal property. This means $\tau_Y = \tau'_Y$.
3. $\tau_Y^s$ is a subspace topology (and thus by 2. the unique subspace topology):
   The "only if" part is trivial because  $\tau_Y^s$ is admissible and for each admissible topology the continuity of $f$ implies the continuity of $i \circ f$. Let us prove the "if" part. Continuity of $i \circ f$ means that $(i \circ f)^{-1}(U) \in \tau_Z$ for all $U \in U_X$. But $(i \circ f)^{-1}(U) = f^{-1}(i^{-1}(U)) = f^{-1}(U \cap Y)$, thus $f^{-1}(V) \in \tau_Z$ for all $V \in \tau_Y^s$, i.e. $f$ is continuous.

Also have a look at [an injective map is embedding iff its left composition with any continuous map is continuous](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4509143).

If you know some category theory, [Attempt to define the notion of subobjects](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4198693) will give you a broader understanding.

Answer (score 6):

## Some topics for you to think about

### Metric spaces

Think of a metric space
\begin{equation*}
  d: X \times X \rightarrow X.
\end{equation*}

1. What would be a good/natural metric to use in some $Y \subset X$?
2. With this induced metric, what would be the neighbourhoods of a certain $a \in Y$?
3. With this induced metric, what topology (open sets) does it give you?
4. With this induced metric, when would it be true that $y_n \in Y$ converges to some $a \in Y$?

### Restricting the co-domain

Given a continuous function $f: X \rightarrow Z$... if you restrict the co-domain to some $A \subset Z$ that contains $f(X)$...

1. Should this new $\tilde{f}: X \rightarrow A$ be continuous?
2. What a topology in $A$ would have to satisfy to make $\tilde{f}$ continuous?

### Restricting the domain

Given a continuous function $f: X \rightarrow Z$... if you restrict the domain to some $A \subset X$...

1. Should $f|_A$ be continuous?
2. What would a topology in $A$ have to satisfy to make $f|_A$ continuous?

### Thinking about nets

If you know about [nets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Net_(mathematics))...

1. A topological space is completely determined if you specify (with consistency) what nets converge and to where. Just like sequences in metric spaces.
2. When exactly a net $y_\lambda \in Y \subset X$ should converge to some $a \in Y \subset X$?
3. What topology in $Y$ gives (for $y_\lambda, a \in Y \subset X$)
   \begin{equation*}y_\lambda \xrightarrow{\tau_Y} a \iff y_\lambda \xrightarrow{\tau_X} a?\end{equation*}